# Find the general solution for $u(x,y)$ of $(y+u)u_{x}+yu_{y}=x-y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general solution for $u(x,y)$ of this problem with the method of Lagrange, but I could not finish my attempt. The Lagrange system we had is $$\frac{dx}{y+u}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{x-y}.$$
Working on this system:
\begin{align}
   & \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{y+u}, \\
   & \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{x-y}{y+u};
\end{align}
I know I should have obtained an expression of $y$ and $u$ in the form of $y(x,c_{1},c_{2})$ and $u(x,c_{1},c_{2})$. However, I could not find that expression and I am confused about how to continue this. Is there a way that anyone can help me to give a clue to find $u(x,y)$?

Comment: Use componendo-divindendo on the second equality and set equal to the first ratio $$ \frac{d(y + u)}{x} = \frac{dx}{y + u} \implies (y + u)^{2} - x^{2} = c_{1}$$ This is equivalent to adding the ODEs that you stated and then separating and integrating. Then use componendo-divindendo on the first and third ratios and set equal to the second ratio $$\frac{d(x + u)}{x + u} = \frac{dy}{y} \implies \frac{x + u}{y} = c_{2}$$ Now use the relationship $c_{2} = f(c_{1})$.

Comment: How did you get $d(y+u)$? @MatthewCassell

Comment: 'This is equivalent to adding the ODEs that you stated and then separating and integrating'.

Comment: Sure, and I got $dy+du$. I don't understand how it is legal to simply write $dy+du=d(y+u)$. I have never been taught about this, so I feel like this is illegal. Do you know what should I search on the internet to learn more about this? Thank you! @MatthewCassell