# Finding Solution of Quasilinear Partial Differential Equation Using Lagrange Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a PDE and wanted to solve it using Lagrange's method

$(y+u) u_x + yu_y=x-y$

so the characteristic equation is

$\frac{dx}{y+u}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{x-y}$

First, I want to work with

$\frac{dx}{y+u}=\frac{dy}{y}$

to find the $C_1$ to make the general solution of PDE : $F(C_1,C_2)=0$

However I'm stuck on this part

$ydy = (y+u) dy$

How do I do the integration of $u(x,y)$ with respect to $y$? Can I do it right away?

Comment: [This is starting to look like a homework problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4875994/find-the-general-solution-for-ux-y-of-yuu-xyu-y-x-y).